# Best way to implement dynamic/cascading ListBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am currently struggling with how best to set up dynamic/cascading listboxes in my application. I have a hierarchical table and I want the user to be able to select from the highest level and the lower level listboxes update based on users higher level selections.

I am working on a WPF/MVVM application using C#

example data:

| Z000 | Z100 | Z200 | Z300 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A000 | A100 | A110 | A111 |
| A000 | A100 | A110 | A112 |
| A000 | A200 | A210 | A211 |
| A000 | A200 | A210 | A212 |
| A000 | A300 | A310 | A311 |
| A000 | A300 | A320 | A321 |
| B000 | B100 | B110 | B111 |
| B000 | B100 | B110 | B112 |
| B000 | B200 | B210 | B211 |
| B000 | B200 | B220 | B222 |
| C000 | C100 | C110 | C111 |
| C000 | C100 | C110 | C112 |
| C000 | C100 | C120 | C121 |
| C000 | C200 | C210 | C211 |

When the application loads it should show four listboxes, each displaying distinct values for Z000, Z100, Z200, Z300.

The user can select an option from any of the listboxes regardless of hierarchy.

Ex. If user selects from the second listbox(Z100) item [*A200*], then all the lower listboxes should update to show distinct values under A200 for Z200[*A210*] and Z300[*A211, A212*]
the higher level listbox should not be affected (Z000)

Sorry for any confusion I am having a hard time describing this scenario in writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the idea of cascading ListBox very interesting. So I created a project that implement that. Please check my GitHub [repo](https://github.com/mwck46/WPF_Apps/tree/master/HierarchicalListboxes). Here are some screenshots. Hope I understand the requirement correctly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort. Your solution clarified some of the issues I was struggling with. I had a difficult time figuring out how to refresh the lower level items and not affect the higher ones, and all my attempts were overly complicated. The child listbox and hierarchy are great. Thanks again!